# What is the X here?--I'm on a X for time

Tags: single-word-requests, filler-words

I'm trying to say I have "less time" these days. I heard my english teacher use a sentence like: "I'm on a crutch for time" and I understood from context that it means they lack time. But years later when I googled that, it's invalid. Is there a filler word that makes the sentence correct? I'm on a X for time. What X works to accurately represent that I lack time?

Comment: Is it possible they were “crunched” for time?

Comment: I’m as busy as a one-armed paper hanger.

Comment: I’m on a roller coaster and it doesn’t look like . . ,

Comment: Are you sure you're not mishearing *in* as *on*? If it's *in,* then X likely = "pinch" or "crunch."

Comment: Yes yes. It was crunch for time. Not crutch.